# Is this question asking for code and self-answered with the code, too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I saw this question:

[Display an arrow pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58323882/display-an-arrow-pattern)

And I'm not sure if it's broad or not. It's [self-answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) from OP and that is fine by me. It's really the *question* that bothers me - leaving the answer aside, it asks for somebody to create a non-trivial application and lacks any specifications.

So, while it's not a problem that it was answered by the OP, it can *only* be answered by the OP. Also, leaving aside the answer, I'm not sure it's answerable. It's a code request with almost no constraints.

Comment: The same user has a bad habit of asking very broad questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58315913/database-design-for-chat-application-for-ecommerce-for-customers-delivery-perso

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, textbook too broad.

That is a typical *"Write my code for me"* question.
Self-answered questions are fine, as long as they can stand on their own, without the added answer. Basically, they should follow the same rules any other question should.

Comment: Except that the site apparently makes exceptions for "special people"...