# Are we playing favorites with high-rep users self-answering off-topic questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation-bias

Consider the following question:

> #### New features of C++20?
>
> I want to know how much is C++20 different from C++17? I mean, the new features added compared to those already existing in C++17. I have seen many mentions to some features like:
>
> - Three-way comparison operator <=>
> - Calendar extensions for the chrono library.
> - Improved multithreading support.
>
> But I don't think that's all. An URL pointing to a site that gives such information is also welcome.

This was closed as off-topic - rightly, in my opinion; it's a request for a list of things (and of an off-site resource, but that's only presented as an option for what an answer might be; also, due disclosure - I was one of the close-voters).

Do you agree it should have been closed? Good. Now consider this question:

> #### What are the new features in C++17?
>
> C++17 is now feature complete, so unlikely to experience large changes. Hundreds of proposals were put forward for C++17.
>
> Which of those features were added to C++ in C++17?
>
> When using a C++ compiler that supports "C++1z", which of those
>   features are going to be available when the compiler updates to C++17?

This should also have been closed by the same logic (even though it doesn't explicitly ask for an external link as an optional answer). Yet...

- [What are the new features in C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060436/what-are-the-new-features-in-c17)   -  is open with over a 1,000 upvotes.
- [New features of C++20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60980438/new-features-of-c20) - was promptly closed, and got 3 downvotes.

The low-rep user who asked the second question rightly asked "why is that one ok but mine is close-worthy?"

A poignant question IMHO.

<sub>No disrespect for Yakk intended.</sub>

Comment: Carrying forward one of the comments, I suspect that it's heavily related to the C++17 author seeing a lack of any such comprehensive list—being familiar with this specific user, I'm confident he would have found one—and deciding to put in the work to create one and share it. Of course I can't say for sure, but I think it's a reasonable guess. The people here have pretty consistently appreciated high effort.

Comment: Clearly there's some contention though, it's been closed and re-opened four times plus another seven unsuccessful trips through the close votes queue.

Comment: And it has 8 other answers that were so poor quality they had to be deleted.

Comment: I strongly appreciate the C++17 question because that was what inspired me to learn it. I frequent this site a lot more than many others so I think that this is a good place for such questions that encourage aknowkedge.

Comment: @lateo96: The thing is, SO should not replicate other, non-Q&A sites, like isocpp.org, or cppreference.com, or even the Wikipedia page on C++20. And that's also true for C++17 - so, IMHO, that question should be closed, even now.

Comment: Can you explain what makes those questions off-topic?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that is what I want to know. The reason claims that I was requesting for an URL, which I removed. So now the reason is inconsistent with the question.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: The tour says: "Don't ask about: ... requests for lists of things." And "features in C++17" is a huge list of things.

Comment: @lateo96: In fairness, your question was closed with the URL request still in it.

Comment: @einpoklum then about half question in this site should be closed. Do you know how many list-related question I've seen here? Also, I think you are being quite pragmatic on this (about the list I mean)

Comment: I know but you said that the other question should be marked as `off-topic` as well, even when it doesn't request for an URL.

Comment: @einpoklum I agree with lateo96 on this. The [help center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on off-topic questions doesn't mention the "asks for a list" thing. I think the mentioned section of the tour (which isn't even normative) is about "lists of off-site resources".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Asking for the list of features of C++17 or 20 is not "a practical ... problem", to quote the helper center page.

Comment: @lateo96: Didn't you mean "dogmatic" rather than "pragmatic" ? :-(

Comment: @einpoklum Half of the \[language-lawyer\] questions are not practical, yet the C++ tag community loves them.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Those are _problems_. They're practical to people who come against them when writing obscure code. Now you could say those people's pursuits are not very practical, but let's not get into that...

Comment: @einpoklum I'd say learning the new features of C++20 can also be a problem, if you don't know what exactly was added.

Comment: @einpoklum maybe, english is not my mother language, but I meant that your comment was based on the final/practical result rather than in the principles or contexts that are beyond that.

Comment: @lateo96: Ah, ok. Anyway, in the far past there were quite a few questions on SO which today would be off-topic, like the [Definitive list of C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). If you ignore those, there should be very few or no "give me the list of X" questions. Can you link to a few examples from recent years?

Comment: "List of C++ books" is off-topic because it "asks for off-site resources". "List of C++20 changes" does not (after the last edit at least). If anything, it could be "too broad".

Comment: @einpoklum Well, 2017 is no exactly the "far past". But I see your point. Still, a question does not have to say "Give me a list" to being actually requesting for a list, at least implicitly.

Comment: @lateo96: Like my answer says - the C++17 answer is, I hope, a fluke. I may be blinded by my own prejudice, but - again, give a few examples. Never mind the title.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat the C++17 question is now `too-broad` and I think you are right, mainly in the "if anything" part, because still the question refers to a very specific and defined thing, that is the new features of a language. Maybe such features can lead to a very broad thing if we talk about the purposes of them, but that's not the case.

Comment: @lateo96 *then about half question in this site should be closed.* I'd go a bit further. Probably a lot further. But I also think that Thanos didn't go far enough.

Comment: Do not take that literally. That was for the comment of @einpoklum saying that my question was closed because the answer expected is a list of things. Many questions here are answered in form of list. If that is the problem, then the list formatting option should be removed.

Comment: @einpoklum take this question as an example, it is 5 years old, not sure if that is too old for you. It asks "Why should I use X and not Y?" And it is right. So if I ask "Why should I use C++20 and not C++17" is rigth despite I am asking the same thing?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623673/why-should-i-use-amazon-kinesis-and-not-sns-sqs

Comment: Here are some more good questions that ask for list of things. All of them are several years old though: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026884/advantages-of-auto-in-template-parameters-in-c17) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514509/advantages-of-using-stdmake-unique-over-new-operator) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17)

Comment: @einpoklum this is also 5 years old. It asks "What is the difference between X and Y". If I ask "What is the difference between C++17 and C++20 is right?"
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda

Comment: The ones provided by @HolyBlackCat are more recent and they are asking for reasons for something.

Comment: @lateo96: Those are not essentially list questions: Different people will describe the difference between pip and conda differently; and answers which are high-level and summarize are better than a list of anything. ... and I wrote the above before looking at the answers. They bear out what I said.

Comment: Consider the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866901 : Is it too broad? Yes. Is it (indirectly) asking for off-site resources? Kind of. Is it off-topic? Probably. Is it a "good question" in the classical sense? Certainly not. So (as it was said similarly in some answers here) I think that what we see here has *absolutely nothing* to do with the reputation of the asker or the answerer (and I wonder why you thought that, but that's another point...)

Comment: Whether "What are the new features in C++17?" is off-topic or not is already discussed in  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326951/are-questions-asking-for-feature-sets-of-specific-software-versions-on-topic... So as long as "New features of C++20?" question can demonstrate that it meets the same reasoning it should be fine... we just need to have answer demonstrating that list is "short" and finite (later is definitely the case as spec if fixed size :) )

Comment: @chris Regarding _"I suspect that it's heavily related to the C++17 author seeing a lack of any such comprehensive list"_ the very first comment to the question posted such a list within 24 hours of the question being asked, and several other links were posted later in comments. And regardless of all that, it's absurd on its face to think that C++ 17 would have been released without a list of the new features. The OP obviously put a lot of effort into that answer, and it's beautifully presented, but it's not as though the information wasn't already available elsewhere.

Comment: @skomisa, My mistake. I should have anticipated those comments would be there.

Comment: @lateo96 "*then about half the questions on this site would be closed*" There are nearly 20 million questions on the site. I doubt more than a few hundred of them are 'what are all the features of X language/version'.

Comment: @TylerH Uffff again... do not take that literally. That was just an answer to an exaggerated comment.

Comment: @lateo96 My point is it is *so* wrong that it's not even right as an exaggerated comment.

Comment: So you aren't even going to mention the large set of discourse revolving around the c++-faq tag in general? Wouldn't you agree that an organized group was more influencial here than simply a single high rep user? Don't you think that was an essential piece to have disclosed here as part of your smear against high reputation users?

Comment: @TylerH I think you misunderstand me. I was replying to a comment against "list of things", no "what are all the features of X language/version" which is a lot more specific. It is still exaggerated, tough.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, we were blinded by what is effectively a long and interesting blog post by Yakk, but which is quite off-topic as an SO answer, and let the question slide without closing it. This served as a poor lesson for @lateo96, who got hit with a closure trying to ask a question in the same vein.

Note that just as I wrote these lines, the C++17 question has been closed as off-topic. ... and reopened the next day.

Answer (score 12):

From what I've seen, it's a general community consensus that self-answered questions on a broad topic are allowed but regular questions on a broad topic are not.

I think that this is because:

- There is no useful information already present on a regular question on a broad topic.
- The OP of the self-answered question often put in an above-average amount of effort in order for the question and answer to be useful.

It's not about whether the user has low reputation or not. That has absolutely no bearing. It's if the question already has useful information with it, in the form of an answer, and has had effort put into it.

Take for example [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings) (plz no Meta effect). This question could be seen as too broad or opinion-based but is a useful question and is self-answered, so it is open. (I admit that some people voted to close this question, but that was because they didn't realize it was a canonical-faq.)

Even the C++17 question itself proves the point:

[image]
...
[image]

You could get all language-lawyery and say that all of these broad-but-useful self-answered questions are off-topic, but then some of the most useful questions on this site would be closed. Noone wants that.

Comment: 1. The example you give is not a "broad topic". 2. The issue with the two questions are that they're asking for a long laundry-list. 3. If this is the norm, and should be the norm, then we have to make it clear to low-rep users how come we're allowing these questions from others but not from them.

Comment: @einpoklum Read the last paragraph again.

Comment: Actually, a lot of useful questions are currently closed or locked, because the rules for good questions changed over time.

Comment: What do you know, Shog himself reopened the C++17 question. Now that's authoritative too.

Comment: @S.S.Anne: I didn't and am not claiming that all broad-but-useful self-answered questions are off-topic. Although - perhaps some of them belong on tag pages.

Comment: @einpoklum It's not about whether the user is low reputation or not. That has absolutely no bearing. It's if the question already has useful information with it, in the form of an answer, and has had effort put into it.

Comment: @S.S.Anne: 1. Newbie, low-rep users don't have the ability to effectively self-answer, and thus skirt the on-topic requirements. 2. You're making a different argument than in your answer, which I believe I have rebutted.

Comment: @einpoklum 1. The button's right there for them to push. 2. ...ok? 3. A biography of Bjarne Stroustrup is not about programming at all, it's about a person.

Comment: @S.S.Anne: 1. You are proving my point about bias. 3. I retracted that comment because I needed a better example. Maybe "list of cool hacks using GCC builtins" or something that might be practically useful and get a lot of votes if people ignored its off-topicness.

Comment: @einpoklum How am I proving the point about bias? The button is right there, in their face. I saw it the first time I asked a question, before I even knew what off-topic meant.

Comment: It's also partly that these incredibly broad questions are asking answerers to do an unreasonably broad amount of work to produce a comprehensive reference for someone who likely only requires a small portion of it.  If you've already done the unreasonably broad amount of work to cover everyone and just want to share it, well, great.

Answer (score 12):

Let's look at this from a practical perspective. The most fundamental difference between the C++17 question and the C++20 question was that the C++17 question was self-answered. The point of closing a question is to prevent it from being answered, so self-answering a question on some level makes question closure less important. And for an answer where edits are encouraged like the C++17 one, closing the question is at best a symbolic gesture.

The horse left the stable the moment you put him in the barn; closing the door isn't helping.

I'm making no value judgments here; I'm not claiming at this point that this state of affairs is good or bad. But this is the effect of the rules we have. The primary mechanism for the community to enforce its rules is question closure to prevent answering. If you self-answer a question, closure becomes a lot less relevant, and thus enforcement as a practical matter is less capable.

So while it may not be our intent for self-answered questions to be able to skirt the rules, that is the way it works out in practice. The only moderation mechanism left after closure is deletion, which requires that the question either attract enough downvotes or direct moderator intervention.

So this is not favoritism per-se. It's simply the result of whether you're posting because you want the answer or you're posting because you want to create a useful artifact for the answer you already more-or-less have. The latter is rewarded because it creates an immediately useful artifact, and it's "allowed" because there's basically nothing that can be done to stop it.

The difference in voting comes from a similar place. Some people will see the question as a violation of our rules and downvote. Others may see it as a useful artifact, but they are far more likely to do so if it actually contains the information they're looking for. This is why there's a 20:1 upvote/downvote ratio on the C++17 question, while the C++20 one is in the negatives.

---

As for whether having this loophole is good, I would say... maybe.

The common legalistic argument is that any question which lives on the site that violates the rules, by merely existing, is an argument for another such question. And it's hard to argue against that because we wouldn't be having this discussion otherwise.

The common argument in favor of the question is that, it adds value to the site. I've referred to it many times myself, Google will find it for you very easily, and nowhere else on the entire Internet has a better, more digestible collection of virtually everything in C++17. Having this information is making the Internet better, which is supposed to be our founding principle.

The legalistic counter-argument is that our rules exist, not because they only cull out garbage, but because the few good artifacts produced by such questions aren't worth allowing the torrents of trash that the rules filter out.

And yet, the C++20 question was downvoted and closed. It's not going anywhere. Though we are discussing this because of the existence of the C++17 question, the actual harm that can be attributed to that question consists of... a quickly closed question and a discussion. So, from a purely practical, utilitarian perspective, the C++17 question's existence has caused far more good than harm.

Personally, I lean against the legalistic viewpoint. I don't feel comfortable with the rigidity, and I don't have a problem with allowing a small plethora of good artifacts to exist which don't follow the rules. Yes, that means every now and then, we have to get on the site and remind everyone that they are *exceptions*, not precedents. But I would say that the good caused by these exceptions typically outweighs the bad.

And it's not like we can't get rid of the bad ones when they appear.

Comment: You might want to elaborate *why* we want to prevent answers: it's not because we're sadistic or anything, it's to prevent *bad* answers to arguably bad questions. With an open ended question like those C++ examples, any *average* answer is guaranteed to be too short and incomplete, and it's highly unlikely that somebody'll spontaneously come along to write an answer complete enough to do the question justice. Having such a partial answer hanging around and possibly becoming canonical is worse than not having the entire question in the first place. That's a non-issue with self-answered Qs.

Comment: "The point of closing a question is to prevent it from being answered" <- That's only a secondary point for questions that are off-topic. Also, what you're describing completely disregards the low-reputation users, who experience a norm which is at best inconclusive and poorly described to them and at worst unfair/discriminatory.

Comment: Also, and this addresses @deceze 's comment - you're rationalizing after the fact. If self-answered "list of things" questions can be on-topic - that needs to be made explicit, and more importantly - it needs to be clear to newbie users what they should and should not ask. So if we continue to make such exceptions, they need to know why they can't.

Comment: @einpoklum I agree, the basic concept of SO is badly conveyed, and barely anyone remembers the *purpose* of SO anymore. The letter of the law is all that most people see these days, its *spirit* has mostly gotten lost. SO is supposed to be something like the Wikipedia of programming in a Q&A format. It's not a place to get *your* question answered, it's a place to *find answers to questions.* If a post is a net positive in this context, it's great. If a post is a net negative for that purpose, it must go.

Comment: Wow. I wish I could've done this good of a job.

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR:

1. Let's not language-lawyer the close reasons; [Yakk's question about C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060436/what-are-the-new-features-in-c17) is useful and should stay.
2. [lateo96's question about C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60980438/new-features-of-c20) might've been closed incorrectly, but it doesn't change the fact that it wasn't received well. Close votes being used as 'super downvotes' is not new.

---

First, the [Yakk's question about changes in C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060436/what-are-the-new-features-in-c17):

I think yes, **we do have a bias** here. Not in favor of high-rep users answering their own questions, but **in favor of questions that have good answers**. I don't think Yakk's question would've been received differently if he didn't have so much rep, or if the answer was posted by someone else.

But this bias is not necessarily a bad thing, in my opinion. Let's not forget that our goal is to 'build a repository of programming knowledge in a Q&A format', and the close reasons (and the other rules we have) are there *only* to facilitate it.

Even though the Yakk's question is *somewhat* broad, that Q&A is a nice addition to the site (in my opinion), so it was received well.

> off-topic ... it's a request for a list of things

A "request for a list of things" is not a close reason, "too broad" is. Whether or not something is too broad is subjective.

The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) elaborates how broad is "too broad":

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Yakk didn't need a book to answer his question. He crammed a complete answer into a single post.

---

Next, the [lateo96's question about C++20 changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60980438/new-features-of-c20):

In my opinion, it might've been closed incorrectly.

But close votes being used as 'super downvotes', while not a good thing, is not new. For example, we often close homework dumps with arbitrary close reasons.

**Note to @lateo96:** Even if the consensus will be that your question is not against the rules, it won't change the fact that the question wasn't received well (score of -4).

The questions on SO are often viewed as (and often are) requests for personal help, rather than suggestions to populate a knowledge base. If you ask for too much (compiling a list of C++20 features is a lot of work), it might be perceived as rude and downvoted.

Even if we reopen your question, I doubt someone (who wouldn't do it otherwise) will put in the hours of effort to provide a decent answer.

Comment: I think TL;DR should be "it is hard to say 'not showing research' to the question that has 10 page long self-answer, while it is pretty much guaranteed to get downvotes for 'list this for me' request"... Otherwise totally agree.

Comment: Linking to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326951/are-questions-asking-for-feature-sets-of-specific-software-versions-on-topic may be useful as it exactly about on-topic-ness of "C++17 features"

Comment: You're right, but your are missing some things. One is that at least the first and second downvote is maybe for the same persons that closed the question. Another is that average users or users with not high reputation do not tend to upvote questions that had been downvoted, and even some tend to downvote them, even without thinking about that. In most cases, question that had been initially downvoted will likely keep a negative record.

Comment: Even if I research and provide a decent answer I'm pretty sure that it will not been reopened.

Comment: Also, I already had an experience with a self-answered question about Qt6 new features that I self-answered and was closed. So thinking on that, I do not think that this answer deserves my upvote, because I don't think that it is true, based on my own experience.

Comment: @lateo96 *"Even if I research and provide a decent answer I'm pretty sure that it will not been reopened"* You wouldn't be able to provide an answer because it's closed. But you're right that it's hard to get a question reopened; sometimes it's easier to ask a new one. If you wait a few days and ask a new question, it has a good chance to not be closed if you write a great answer (and especially if you word the question to not look off-topic: no requests for URLs, etc).

Comment: @lateo96 *"your are missing some things. One is that at least the first and second downvote is maybe for the same persons that closed the question"* Yes, it's possible. I think I mentioned it, but maybe my wording wasn't very clear. When I said that "close votes are being used as super-downvotes", I meant that people often close-vote in addition to downvoting, when they think a simple downvote isn't enough.

Comment: @lateo96 *"I already had an experience with a self-answered question about Qt6 new features that I self-answered and was closed"* Self-answering doesn't unconditionally make your question on-topic. It often *improves* how the question is received to a some degree, but if the question is blatantly off-topic, it will still be closed. Can you link to that question?

Comment: I tried, sorry, but it was deleted. I also google about how to get the link of a deleted question but it says that I need at least 10K of reputation, sorry... :-(

Comment: @lateo96 You might find it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile), or in your browser history. I think you'll be able to view the question even without 10K rep since you posted it.

Comment: But it was more than 60 days ago... so it is not "recent" no?

Comment: @lateo96 Yep, if it's so old, then it's not in that list. But it should still exist, so a link from your browser history would work. Though looking for it probably doesn't worth the effort.

Comment: Yes, and also, my sister is kind of intrusive so I delete the browser's history from time to time.

Comment: _"Let's not <...> close; question is useful and should stay."_ Closure is not the same as deletion. Closure signals that a question isn't a good fit for SO, even if it's useful.

Answer (score 7):

It's not just high rep users.  If you're Famous Enough™, you can get away with it too.

<sup>*Don't* make me link to examples.  You can find one or two in some of my more recent and prominent Meta questions.</sup>

*Ideally*, we treat questions equally in that, if a question is off-topic, it really doesn't matter who asks it or how many votes it has.  There does seem to be a bit of a warp which happens in that users can just...not follow that convention because more votes somehow overrules topicality.

From what I can see, the community *might* be coming together to right the issue at hand; no disrespect to the OP intended, but the question is still off-topic.

Just hope that the OP doesn't email Stack Overflow, Inc. to convince people to reopen it.

Comment: *"no respect to the OP intended"* - Freudian slip

Comment: Side note: community already "coming together" at least once on that particular "C++17 features" question - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326951/are-questions-asking-for-feature-sets-of-specific-software-versions-on-topic with roughly 3:1 split favoring "on-topic".

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica:  You surely knew that I meant "**no** disrespect to the OP intended".

Answer (score 4):

#### Why do we close questions?

Because it prevents answers from being be posted.

#### Why do we want to prevent answers from being posted?

Because we want to prevent *bad* answers from being posted.

#### Why do we want to prevent *bad* answers from being posted?

Because once a question exists it's supposed to be canonical, e.g. it will show up in Google results and can be used as a duplicate target. If that question becomes *the* canonical post about new C++ features, and it contains only bad answers, that's worse for everyone.

#### Why do we presume to know that some questions can only beget bad answers?

That's arguably very subjective, but mostly: experience. The *average* answer on SO is pretty short. It's the rare outliers where a user took many hours crafting a superb answer with many thousands of words. It is *highly unlikely* that such answers will spontaneously come about by random passers-by. More likely an open-ended question such as those C++ examples will spawn many short, incomplete, mutually incoherent answers, if any at all. They will be collectively worse as a canonical response to the question than not having that question in the first place.

If it's foreseeable that the only answer that could appropriately cover the question requires *substantial* effort to write, which is unlikely to spontaneously happen, then <strike>it's *"too broad"*</strike> it *needs more focus* and is overall better off closed.

#### Why does this not apply to self-answered questions?

Because with self-answered questions an appropriate answer is already given, so it becomes a non-issue. A broad question with a great answer is a net positive for this *knowledge base of programming related topics*, so we're happy to have it.

Reputation isn't the issue, the presence or absence of an answer and the likelihood of that answer emerging is. That question which remained open was self-answered and already contained [a substantial answer at the time it was posted](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38060437/1), which has since been expanded in [dozens of revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38060437/revisions) over the years. The same cannot be said about the question that got closed, and it's not foreseeable that that question will receive an answer of similar quality. If anyone was inclined to compile such a list, they would do it of their own volition and could post it as a self-answered question.

Comment: I don't see why the C++17 question should stay open. It got an answer. It is unlikely to get another answer of comparable quality. The answer can still be edited if needed even if the question is closed. To me it just feels "inconsistent" to leave an off-topic question open just because it got a self-answer. Are there any effects that closing a question has that I am missing? According to the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) the main difference between an open and a closed question is that a closed question can not get any new answers.

Comment: Again, the main purpose of closing a question is to signal to the OP that the question requires improvements and that answers won't be accepted until the question has been improved. The point of that is to prevent *bad answers*, which may be posted because the question is too vague or not focused enough. You see this all the time in tags like [tag:php], where some vague coding puzzle leads to half a dozen really terrible answers quickly which just spread a bad understanding of the language because the question itself was fundamentally flawed and can't be answered well.

Comment: Generally the same goes for questions which are too broad; they usually cannot be answered in any appropriate manner and would just leave half-answered ruins which many people might stumble across but which all would find unsatisfactory. Since a great answer already exists, that's of no practical concern. Yes, in the case of self-answered questions the question is somewhat judged based on the answer. But let's be practical: we want a useful, quality knowledge base of programming related wisdom. All the tools like question closing work towards this purpose. Don't put the cart before the horse.

Comment: As I've said elsewhere - you're only providing one reason for closing questions. Off-topic questions are closed, on their own and regardless of answers.

Comment: What about the new users who use questions like this being open as justification for posting their own bad questions?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery my understanding of deceze's idea is: it's the questioner's responsibility to prove that the question is on-topic. Common way is to provide information in the question, but for opinion based and too-broad questions providing correct complete authoritative self-answer is another way. I don't see it really expanding what is "on-topic" but rather shows a way for questions that *only look* off-topic to stay on site. In this particular case we can argue if list of 40+ items is "too broad" (I think yes) or not but everyone can check correctness and completeness of the answer...

Answer (score 2):

To expand on S.S. Anne's [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396177/208273) (which I agree with completely) a bit, a strict interpretation of "broad, but with a good self-answer" questions as off-topic would badly inhibit the ability to write canonical FAQs.

Consider these (excellent, please don't close-vote them) questions for Java/Android:

[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

[Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

[What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

On their face, every one of these would be clearly off-topic if asked today without a self-answer (even if some of them may have been non⁠–self-answers long ago).

But they're extremely helpful to have around, especially because people ask specific versions of them *all the time*—they have, respectively, 9710, 1322, and 637 linked questions—and it's useful to have a canonical place to point to, rather than having to give basically the same answer (e.g., "`foo` is null, figure out why") to hundreds or thousands of ever-so-slightly different questions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problem with the question, as long as it is *specific* and answers are kept brief and of high technical quality. The question itself needs to be phrased so that it asks for a narrow enough scope and not "write me a book about everything new in C++11".

A question along the lines of "What exactly is the difference between C++X and C++Y" can be summarized with a list of features, but coming up with such a list is not necessarily trivial! It isn't as easy as to just copy the list from the standard, because those lists are known to be both incomplete and also hard to understand for the average programmer.

Take this as an example: [Are all of the features of C99 also in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524553/are-all-of-the-features-of-c99-also-in-c). This list was based on the standards, but had to be manually adjusted with some research effort. The question isn't as trivial to answer as "just RTFM". (And lets not even mention the extremely low quality appendix of the C++ standard listing "all" the difference between C and C++.)

These kind of posts are also very helpful to keep around as canonical duplicates. Overall, they are useful for a whole lot of people.

If you want to wage wars against list-style posts, there's *far* worse cases swimming around out there: [Delete the list of random books?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295460/delete-the-list-of-random-books)

Answer (score -18):

Self answering (what Yakk did, and your post omits) makes a difference. It is directly encouraged in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

> If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

This is inline with the SO model being a repository of knowledge and not a plain Q&A site.

And that spirit of sharing is very likely what affected people's perception of it, causing them to hit the button that says "this post is useful".

As for your cheeky question in the title. No, we don't. I doubt Yakk's post would have been received differently if it had been posted by a user with 100 rep.

Comment: But if the question is off-topic, why should the self-answer - interesting though it is - make a difference?

Comment: I was under the impression that self-answered questions still have to stand as a good question independent of the answer.

Comment: Indeed - I've [asked about this before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390263/is-this-question-asking-for-code-and-self-answered-with-the-code-too-broad) when I wasn't sure and a self-*answer* doesn't waive the quality requirement for the *question*. If the question is off-topic *regardless of the answer*, then the question is still off-topic.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery - The upvote button mentions posts being "useful", not some objective notion of good. I suspect people have no qualms finding a post that is meant to share information with them as useful.

Comment: @einpoklum - Because it does. Doing all the work to share with strangers (under a Q&A model, silly as it may be) is different than hoping for someone to do it on ones behalf. That alters the perception, and the tendency to vote.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica there are more agreements in the linked dupe. You are also free to show an authoritative resource that says that questions that are self-answers are not subject to quality control.

Comment: @VLAZ Self answers [do not get a pass](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235177/what-are-limitations-on-self-answered-questions/235179#235179) in any way. That's from someone who was an authoritative source at the time of posting.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica But the *question* on its own is exactly as useful as the other one. Stack Overflow isn't a blog platform, and as einpoklum suggested above it shouldn't try to be.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: In that case I'm sure you'll not close my upcoming question "What is the most popular limmerick about C++?", which I will answer starting with "There was a Bjarne from Nantucket".

Comment: @einpoklum - No, I won't. I don't find it "useful".

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: What if 1,000 people find it useful because they are inspired by limmericks? :-\

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica you are confusing upvotes with close votes. The two are not diametrically opposite. One can find a post *useful* but still *off-topic*. And vice versa - on-topic but not useful. The latter should not be closed, the former - should.

Comment: @einpoklum - It's their prerogative. Such is the nature of having a "useful" criteria for voting.

Comment: @einpoklum It [might become locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) although I admit that's not a self-answer but it certainly is popular.

Comment: @VLAZ - I am not confusing anything with anything. The OP clearly stated they wish to understand why one post has 1000 upvotes (supposedly adding some insult to injury), I clearly answered that.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica OP clearly asks "*why is that one ok but mine is close-worthy?*", the 1,000 upvotes being just a fact worth-mentioned and not the question.

Comment: @desertnaut - No, the question is about playing favorites. That *includes* the 1000 votes. And it's not *their* C++20 post.

Comment: @VLAZ "on-topic" is somewhat tag-specific. What if there was just stream of "can I do XXX in C++17" completely on-topic questions at that time and broad answer by Yakk was put there to serve as universal duplicate? Like "Null Reference/Pointer Exception"  questions for each language... Clearly people in that tag did not find post off-topic (and note that C/C++ community put efforts into maintaining similar questions like famous "C book list" - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355588/the-c-book-list-has-gone-haywire-what-to-do-with-it)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you'd notice that I've not actually argued whether the question discussed is on-topic or not. That's because I honestly cannot say. What I did do is say that self-answers are not exempt from quality requirements. I stand by that statement. If a question is self-answered *but off-topic*, then it should be closed. I did actually VTC one today. If a question is a self-answered *and* on-topic then there is no issue. Whether the specific question discussed here is on-topic or not is for others to decide.